# Differing return type for virtual functions

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual-functions, return-type, covariant

A virtual function's return type should be the same type that is in base class, or covariant. But why do we have this restriction?

Comment: You expected the return type of the overriding function to be allowed to be...?

Answer (score 13):

Because of the nonsense that would ensue:

```
struct foo
{
    virtual int get() const { return 0; }
};

struct bar : foo
{
    std::string get() const { return "this certainly isn't an int"; }
};

int main()
{
    bar b;
    foo* f = &b;

    int result = f->get(); // int, right? ...right?
}
```

It isn't sensible to have a derived class return something completely unrelated.

Comment: Discussion [moved to chat.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15288/discussion-between-gmannickg-and-curiousguy)

Comment: Conclusion of the chat: **GManNickG admits that the current C++ rule which only allows pointers (or references) could be relaxed.**

Comment: The question here was: "But why do we have **this** restriction?" so your answer would be: "for no reason"???

Answer (score 5):

Because how would the code that's using the return value cope with all sorts of unrelated types coming back?  e.g.:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual float func();
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    virtual char *func();
};

A *p = (some_condition) ? new A() : new B();
p->func();  // Oh no! What is the type?
```

Comment: Yes, unrelated type = bad. What about other related types?

Answer (score 3):

According to C++ Standard:

> The return type of an overriding function shall be either identical to the return type of the overridden func-
>   tion or covariant with the classes of the functions. If a function D::f overrides a function B::f, the
>   return types of the functions are covariant if they satisfy the following criteria:
>
> 1) *both are pointers to classes or references to classes*
>
> 2) *the class in the return type of B::f is the same class as the class in the return type of D::f, or is an
>   unambiguous and accessible direct or indirect base class of the class in the return type of D::f*
>
> 3) *both pointers or references have the same cv-qualification and the class type in the return type of D::f
>   has the same cv-qualification as or less cv-qualification than the class type in the return type of B::f.*

Comment: The question already supposes the restriction, it's asking why this restriction exists.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very similar to the one given for ["Why can't I assign a vector<Apple*> to a vector<Fruit*>?"](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#conversion) on Bjarne Stroustrup's FAQ.

The ability to modify the return type would lead to a hole in the type safety of the language (see the answer from @GManNickG for a specific example) when dealing with polymorphic types.

There is one fairly common situation when affecting the return type would be ideal: when returning a polymorphic pointer from a virtual method of a base type. For example,

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual Base* parent() = 0;
};

class Child : public Base {
public:
    Base* parent() override
    {
        return parent_;
    }
private:
    Parent* parent_;  // Assume `Parent` type exists.
};
```

Here we lost the type information that `Child` knows about it's `parent_` member. This leads to lots of casting, even though the type was at one point well defined. We can solve this using the [Curiously Recurring Template Parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (CRTP) idiom,

```
template<class ParentType>
class Base {
public:
    virtual ParentType* parent()
    {
        return parent_;
    }

private:
    ParentType* parent_;

};

class Child : public Base<Parent> {
};
```

Comment: "_The answer is very similar to the one given for "Why can't I assign a vector<Apple*> to a vector<Fruit*>?" on Bjarne Stroustrup's FAQ._" It is not similar in any way. "_The ability to modify the return type would lead to a hole in the type safety of the language_" The ability to modify the return type **without any constraint** is obviously not type safe. That does not answer the original question "why do we have **this restriction**?" not "why do we have any restriction?"